# Search a String in a directory- Get output without filename

Tags: linux, grep, find, ksh, xargs

I am executing the below command to display the lines which matches the pattern.

> find ./files/ -name "*.txt" -print0 | xargs -0 grep "5|20150507"

And output is

*./files/N1.942_0000.txt:78787878|13|5|20150507221152
./files/N1.942_0000.txt:78787878|13|5|20150507221156
./files/N1.943_0002.txt:1221212|13|5|20150507222004
./files/N1.810_0000.txt:8892716618|13|5|20150507215150
./files/N1.442_0001.txt:8648648648|13|5|20150507221636
./files/N1.442_0001.txt:8648648648|13|5|20150507221638
./files/N1.442_0001.txt:7406079160|13|5|20150507221941*

But i want output without file name like below.

*78787878|13|5|20150507221152

78787878|13|5|20150507221156

1221212|13|5|20150507222004

8892716618|13|5|20150507215150

8648648648|13|5|20150507221636

8648648648|13|5|20150507221638

7406079160|13|5|20150507221941*

Comment: Check if your system's version of grep supports the `-h` or `--no-filename` option

Comment: @steeldriver may as well post that as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use grep with option "-h" .

```
 -h, --no-filename
             Suppress  the  prefixing  of file names on output.  This is    
  the default when there is only one file (or only standard input) to
          search.
```

> find ./files/ -name "*.txt" -print0 | xargs -0 grep -h "5|20150507"

Answer (score 2):

`grep` command have `-r` option

it searchs text recursive over directory

example below:

```
grep -r "5|20150507" ./ | awk -F ':' {'print $2'}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
find ./files/ -name "*.txt" -print0 | xargs -0 grep "5|20150507" | awk 'BEGIN{FS=":"} {print $2}'
```

You may have to play with the delimiter "FS=" as it could be a special character.